# bash: phython3: command not found

Tags: command-line, kali-linux

I'm trying to get sherlock to run and I keep getting this error:

```
kali@kali:~$ sudo ln -snf python2.7 /usr/bin/python
[sudo] password for kali: 
kali@kali:~$ sudo ln -s ../local/python/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/python3': File exists
kali@kali:~$ sudo ln -s ../local/python/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/python3': File exists
kali@kali:~$ sudo apt-get install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.8.2-2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgfapi0 libgfrpc0 libgfxdr0 libglusterfs0 libpython3.7-dev python3.7-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 918 not upgraded.
kali@kali:~$ cd sherlock
kali@kali:~/sherlock$ python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4>=4.8.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (4.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: bs4>=0.0.1 in /home/kali/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (0.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2019.6.16 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama>=0.4.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=4.4.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PySocks>=1.7.0 in /home/kali/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.22.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7)) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-futures>=1.0.0 in /home/kali/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 8)) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>=1.9.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 9)) (1.9.5)
Requirement already satisfied: stem>=1.8.0 in /home/kali/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 10)) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: torrequest>=0.1.0 in /home/kali/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 11)) (0.1.0)
kali@kali:~/sherlock$ phython3 sherlock.py johnkelly
bash: phython3: command not found
kali@kali:~/sherlock$
```

Comment: `phython3 sherlock.py johnkelly bash: phython3: command not found` this looks like a simple typo (p**h**ython3 should be python3)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not `phython3`, it's `python3`, like [Monty Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python).